# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I recently started developing a discord bot using `discord.js`, and when I'm trying to run this command, it is raising an error when I update the bot at the line where I execute the command (`client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);`).

The error is:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get'
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shushan\Desktop\discordbot\main.js:18:25)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28) )
```

And here are my code files:

`main.js`

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '?';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Shushbot is online!");
})

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'kick') {
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
    }
})

client.login('SECURITY TOKEN');
```

`kick.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: 'This Command Kicks People!',
    execute(message, args) {
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("This User Has Been Kicked From The Server.");
        } else {
            message.channel.send("This User Couldn't Be Kicked.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check that : https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#reading-command-files

So far, your bot (client) don't know the `commands` method, and even if he knows, `get` dosent exists at all.

You have to write some code to create and set these commands, exemple from doc :

```js
client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    // Set a new item in the Collection
    // With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}
```

You can do it that way or an other, but at this time your object is empty.

Even your `client.commands` is undefined !